# Queuing jobs in PHP

Tags: php, asynchronous, queue

I have a situation here, to be done using PHP, where I am stuck up.
I have around 50 tables filled with information. Whenever, User supplies new Information, I have to compare this data with all the 50 tables to find the matches. Initially, I was making the User wait until the Comparison is over. This is taking a lot of time due to the huge volume of data. However the execution at some point of time completes successfully.

Instead of making the user wait for such a long time, I intended to run this execution in the background. In this way the user can check back after few hours and get the results. Now, another User may upload another set of information immediately and I have to repeat the process again i.e., in the background. I have tried to run these executions in a loop one after the other and I get TIME OUT.

The solution I thought of now is QUEUE or putting the jobs somehow in a STACK. In this way, we should be able to check at any point of time, which jobs are processing or which jobs are complete.

I am not thinking of CRON at the moment, because CRON will execute after fixed intervals and it has to figure out which jobs are complete or still processing.

Please help me if there is any other better way of solving the problem.

Comment: A messaging queue application sounds like the right tool for the job.

Comment: Seems like you could just use a combination of CRON and an extra table to store the jobs.

Comment: PHP is already capable using [messaging queues](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.msg-send.php). For more advanced solutions you can use solutions like Redis or RabbitMQ.